# Sum up a column table xml

Tags: xslt, html-table, sum

I am new to xsl.
I am trying to sum all prices of a table and put the sum in a new row.
but when I run it, I get only one value. Can't understand why.
any ideas?

```
<xsl:for-each select="Album[count(. | key('albums-by-country', Country)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:sort select="Country" />
        <h4 style="color:green;"><xsl:value-of select="Country" style="color:red;" /><br /></h4>


                  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#979994">
      <th style="text-align:left">Price</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Link</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Company</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Name</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Date</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('albums-by-country', Country)"> 
<xsl:sort select="Date" />
   <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Price"/></td>
          <xsl:variable name="PriceBase" select="Price" />
    <xsl:variable name="calculatedTotal" select="Album/total/score" />
    <xsl:variable name="calculatedTotal" select="$PriceBase + $calculatedTotal" />
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Link"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Company"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
      <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length(Date)>4">
      <td><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(Date,5,2),'/',substring(Date,7,8),'/',substring(Date,1,4))"/></td>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="concat('01/01/',substring(Date,1,4))"/></td>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
      <td style="color:red;"><xsl:value-of select="Artist"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
      <tr>

                <td colspan="2">Total Amount</td>
                <td bgcolor="#ffff00"><xsl:value-of select="sum(Album/Price)"/></td>
            </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Try whether changing `<xsl:value-of select="sum(Album/Price)"/>` to `<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('albums-by-country', Country)/Album/Price)"/>` fixes it.

Comment: thanks!!! select="sum(key('albums-by-country', Country)/Price)"/></td>
            </tr>
did the job